# How to remove all .pdf files from a git push

Tags: git

I have a commit and `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r fef3ea9ff1ba8d62049fd5f3bc4e2e8a2c08bfd3` outputs all the files in the commit.

The files are in different folders and many are .pdf files

I try: `git rm *.pdf`

and it says: `fatal: pathspec '*.pdf' did not match any files`

How do I remove all the .pdf files from the commit?

**EDIT 1**

I try: `git rm -r  *.pdf` and it gives:

```
fatal: pathspec '*.pdf' did not match any files
```

**EDIT 2**

```
sudo git rm -r */*.pdf
```

gives

```
fatal: pathspec 'MyFolder/my_file.pdf' did not match any files
```

my_file.pdf is the 1st file listed in the `git diff-tree` output

Answer (score 2):

To remove all `*.pdf` files you can do:

```
git ls-files '*.pdf' | xargs git rm
```

This assumes that the files still exist.

To update the top-most commit so that it removes the files (in addition to whatever else it changes), you do:

```
git commit --amend
```

To remove the files from a commit that is somewhere down in the recent history, look for `git rebase --interactive` and do the above two after you have marked the commit to be changed with `edit` in the TODO list that is presented to you.

To remove the files from all commits that are buried deep down in the history, look for `git filter-branch`.

In all cases, the caveats about rewriting history that has already been published apply.

Answer (score 1):

```
git rm -r */*.pdf
```

- you need to activate the recursive flag and prefix the filespec with */

Comment: you are correct, sorry, I do that and it gives the same result.

Answer (score 1):

If a git status shows those files as deleted from your current working tree, you can make sure they are recorded as deleted for the next commit:

```
 git ls-files --deleted | xargs git rm
```

IF they are not deleted, you can find them and remove them:

```
 git ls-files | grep '\.pdf$' | xargs git rm
```

If they are present in past commits and you want to clean your history from any pdf file, check out [BFG repo cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) (and its [issue 78](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/issues/78#issuecomment-220154977)):

```
bfg -D "*.pdf" myrepo.git
```